# SearchView with ListView changes item positions, need exact item IDs for other activity

Tags: android, listview, searchview

Hello I have a searchview to filter results within a short list. I currently use an integer to pass to the next activity to load up what needs to be displayed. However if you search, the item you search for is now at position 0 which is what the first item would be. So how do I set up a unique ID system for this or is there a method I can call for this?

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_clinics);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayList<String> clinicInfoArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    clinicInfoArrayList.add("Phoenix Urgent Care \n 3931 E Camelback Rd, Phoenix, AZ 85018");
    clinicInfoArrayList.add("Pain Stop North Phoenix Clinic \n 3329 East Bell Road, Suite A2-A5, Phoenix, AZ 85032");
    clinicInfoArrayList.add("The Little Clinic \n 2727 W Bell Rd, Phoenix, AZ 85053");
    clinicInfoArrayList.add("Native Health \n Building C, 4041 N Central Ave, Phoenix, AZ 85012");
    clinicInfoArrayList.add("Allied Clinic, PLLC \n 1147 E Glendale Ave, Phoenix, AZ 85020");
    clinicInfoArrayList.add("Neighborhood Clinic \n 1929 W Fillmore St, Phoenix, AZ 85009");
    clinicInfoArrayList.add("MinuteClinic \n 4742 E Indian School Rd, Phoenix, AZ 85018");


    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.menu_search);


    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            clinicInfoArrayList);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                long arg3) {



            Intent intent = new Intent(SearchClinics.this,ClinicInfoView.class);


            int something = (int)arrayAdapter.getItemId(position);



         intent.putExtra("Another", something);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
            getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
   mSearchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.
            getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    return true;

}


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        listView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        listView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }
    return true;
}

 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: Pass your object instead itemId, i guess getItemId() just return position of item. You can get the object from your list, `clinicInfoArrayList.get(position)` inside `onItemClick`

Comment: The problem is, position is a number that changes when the text is filtered from the SearchView. So for example in the listview item number 5 if searched for is now item number 0 based on the position value because the listview only shows the searched one. So position isn't helpful at all in any of this because it will always give the wrong one.

Comment: If clinic's name is unique, loop, check name matchs, and then you get di the object.

Comment: Or create custom adapter for your case

Comment: arg3 is id of that item

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I fixed it this way,Note I am trying to convert my kotlin logic into java, correct me if there is any mistake ,firstly we need to implement our filtering logic, check onQueryTextChange on the implementation logic

```
    import android.app.SearchManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SearchView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by dr_success on 9/16/2017.
     */

    public class test  extends AppCompatActivity{

        //filtered list here
        final ArrayList<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayList<String> clinicInfoArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        ListView listView;

        SearchView mSearchView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_clinics);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            clinicInfoArrayList.add("Phoenix Urgent Care \n 3931 E Camelback Rd, Phoenix, AZ 85018");
            clinicInfoArrayList.add("Pain Stop North Phoenix Clinic \n 3329 East Bell Road, Suite A2-A5, Phoenix, AZ 85032");
            clinicInfoArrayList.add("The Little Clinic \n 2727 W Bell Rd, Phoenix, AZ 85053");
            clinicInfoArrayList.add("Native Health \n Building C, 4041 N Central Ave, Phoenix, AZ 85012");
            clinicInfoArrayList.add("Allied Clinic, PLLC \n 1147 E Glendale Ave, Phoenix, AZ 85020");
            clinicInfoArrayList.add("Neighborhood Clinic \n 1929 W Fillmore St, Phoenix, AZ 85009");
            clinicInfoArrayList.add("MinuteClinic \n 4742 E Indian School Rd, Phoenix, AZ 85018");


            mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.menu_search);


            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    clinicInfoArrayList);

            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                        long arg3) {



                    Intent intent = new Intent(SearchClinics.this,ClinicInfoView.class);


                   int itemId = (int)arrayAdapter.getItemId(position);

                    String somethingText;

                    //if the filtered list is not empty, get the item from there
                    if(!filteredList.isEmpty()){
                        somethingText = filteredList.get(itemId);
                    }else{
                         somethingText = clinicInfoArrayList.get(itemId);
                    }

                    intent.putExtra("Another", somethingText);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });


        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
            mSearchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();

            mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.
                    getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));


            mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
            mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
            return true;

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                //clear filtered list, so to avoid problems
                filteredList.clear()

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
   ;

                return false;
            }

            for(int i=0;i <= clinicInfoArrayList.size();i++){

                String clinicInfoText = clinicInfoArrayList.get(i);

                if(clinicInfoText.contains(clinicInfoText)){
                    filteredList.add(clinicInfoText);
                }


                final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        clinicInfoArrayList);

                //reset the adapter
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                listView.notify();
            }



            return true
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This line worked for me arrayAdapter.getItemId(position)